# Hang up when want to delete some files in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nautilus, delete, 20.04

I upgraded to 20.04 from 18.04, but now i have got problem with deleting the files from nautilus.

i don`t know why ?! when i was to deleting about 1200 files at same times gnome-shell consume my ram about 7 Gig.